# NDepend - Detect indirectly dependent libraries

Tags: .net, ndepend

I did following example project:

SubClassLibrary - does not use any other DLL besides the .Net Framework

ClassLibrary - this does use SubClassLibrary

Main Program - this uses ClassLibrary directly

If I run NDepend on the Main Program's solution, it only detects the dependency on "ClassLibrary", but not the dependency on "SubClassLibrary" (via ClassLibrary)

When I move "ClassLibrary" to "Application Assemblies" (within Project Settings in NDepend) the dependency is found.

Is there any other way to resolve the "sub-" dependency?

Thanks,
Johannes

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need one?

NDepend analyzes the dependencies between the assemblies that you have included in your analysis. I can't see that something different would make sense...

Thomas

Comment: I want to answer the following question with the help of NDepend: 
Which 3rd Party Libraries are used by my application directly or indirectly. Indirectly == via my "Base Libraries" (our "Framework")

Comment: NDepend won't exactly answer this question. You could use .NET Reflector to do that, but you would have to go through the dependency lists manually...